# C++ find substring with character mutation?

Tags: string, c++11, stl

say, I have a string

```
abcdefkkkkk
```

and I have a pattern `defg` ,and want to match `defk` from the above string ,which means allow a different character.

so I want to get `defk` from the string(or the location in the string), is there an efficient way to do this, in case my pattern may have more mutations, like `def**` or `*def*` (* means any character is ok)?

In general, I have a string , and a pattern ,and I allow a certain number of not match (like `defg` match `defk` in the string).

Comment: Why not use `std::regex`?

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching (provides references to some algorithms).